# Алгоритм детекта перемещения файлов

Tags: алгоритм

Делаю зеркало в облако с непрямым зеркалированием - структура файлов локально не совпадают со структурой файлов на сервере и для этого хранится соответствие "path->path" в базе данных.

Хочется гонять трафик по минимуму. Для этого нужно детектить перемещенные файлы и просто фиксировать изменения в базе данных без перезаливки на сервер.

Про файлы мы знаем: хеш, размер, время модификации. На основе этих данных мы можем просканировать каталог и получить:

- файл добавлен
- файл изменен (+старые данные для этого пути)
- файл удален (+старые данные для этого пути)

На основании этого нужно понять где было перемещение.

Возьмем сразу сложный случай. Вот простой список разных файлов (если не указано иначе)

```
1
2
3
4 (равен файлу 1 по размеру, хешу и дате - то есть дубликат с другим именем)
5
```

происходят трансформации переименования

```
5 -> 6
4 -> 5
2 -> 3
1 -> 2
```

сканирование получает статус файлов

```
1 [удален]  (1 -> 2)
2 [изменен] (1 -> 2)
3 [изменен] (2 -> 3)
4 [удален]  (4 -> 5)
5 [изменен] (4 -> 5)(теперь это дубликат файла 2)  
6 [добавлен] (5 -> 6)
```

Если подумать, то общий алгоритм детекта такой:

1. Пройтись по удаленным файлам и выяснить попал ли этот файл в добавленные или измененные. Если да, то файл был перемещен (и связку "удаление - добавление" нужно заменить на перемещение
2. Пройтись по измененным и посмотреть где может быть новое назначение файла и если нигде, то значит нас просто кто-то перезаписал и файл получает статус "удален"

Но у нас есть коллизии, при которых мы не можем понять куда именно был перемещен в файл (дубликаты в варианта) и для таких случаев неизбежно придется что-то перезаливать. Но не могу придумать алгоритм для работы с коллизиями, чтобы в результате всех манипуляций всегда получался правильный результат.

Answer (score 2):

Если положиться на хэш полностью - то есть считать, что никакие два разных файла не могут иметь один и тот же хэш - то просто поддерживается база данных

```
(хэш, путь в облаке, (пути на диске (может быть много)))
```

При каждом сканировании достаточно простого обновления базы. Есть такой хэш? Прописываем новые пути, старые удаляем. Нет? новый файл. Есть хэш, который вообще не засветился? удаляем из базы - возможно, в корзину (вдруг восстановится на диске).

Осталось использовать такой хэш, который бы не имел коллизий - но неужели какого-нибудь sha1 для практических целей не хватит?
Да, я знаю, ломали его... но неужели вы всерьез этого опасаетесь? :)

Comment: Основной упор на "береги трафик". Дубликаты это норма и могут быть перенесены 2+ дубликата и алгоритм не сможет составить правильные цепочки "источник-цель". У меня есть стойкая мысль "а какая разница в правильности если база данных хранит все равно конечный вариант (а там дубликаты), а источники исчезнут", но мое сознание так сфокусировано на минимизации сетевых операций, что я никак не могу сформулировать шаги полного алгоритма и как убедиться что не будет проблем во всех возможных вариантах